# Separate bundles for mobile and desktop with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to build two separate bundles from a single code base by having two entry points that point to the same file. The difference is that required files with `.mobile` in their name should not be included (noops) in the desktop bundle and vice-versa.
This is pretty easy to do do by running webpack two times and using the `null-loader` based on two separate configs but I was wondering if it would somehow be possible in a single run for performance reasons.
Any ideas?

Comment: This might be of use to you http://tooling.github.io/book-of-modern-frontend-tooling/

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm more than a year late, but if you are still interested in know how this is done, here is the way I achieved this:

```
{

  entry: {

    'desktop/index': './js/desktop/index.js',
    'desktop/post': './js/desktop/post.js',
    'desktop/vendor': [
      'jquery'
    ],

    'mobile/index': './js/mobile/index.js',
    'mobile/vendor': [
      'jquery'
    ]

  },

  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: 'chunk.[chunkhash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['desktop/common', 'desktop/vendor'],
      chunks: ['desktop/common', 'desktop/index', 'desktop/post'],
      minChunks: 2
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['mobile/common', 'mobile/vendor'],
      chunks: ['mobile/common', 'mobile/index'],
      minChunks: 2
    })
  ]

};
```

I [made a repo](https://github.com/MtDalPizzol/webpack-multi-starter) you can clone to see this working. Just be aware that, for now, you'll have to manually change the **src** of the **script** tags in the **.html** files.